# Send Echo(s) from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I remember I had previously some 3 lines of code that could send all Echo(s) in a PHP file to jQuery when a page is loaded.

I Wonder what are those 3 lines I can't find them anymore.

Comment: This is far too vague. Please read [ask]

Comment: PHP donesnt "send things" to jquery. that's not how it works. jQuery requests things **from** php/

Comment: Pootie Tang: I don't really care, I just wanted those 3 lines of code to make what I wanted work like I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

PHP : assume that this is file.php

```
<?php 
    echo "Hello World...!";
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$.post("file.php",function(data){
   alert(data); //this shows Hello World...!
});
```

Comment: This could be an alternative but I still remember about one without data in it.

Comment: Then you should use PHP codes within JavaScript codes.
`<script>`
`val = <?php echo "Hello" ; ?>`
`alert(val)`
`</script>`

Comment: thats not the code I remember. I lost it.

Comment: did u try using **Browser History** to navigate that page..?

Comment: @JakeA - then Google it. There are several AJAX functions in jQuery, maybe `load()` is what you want, but either way, SO is for solving your problems, not helping you remeber things, and this will solve your problem, regardless of whatever you may have seen or used before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var = 'php data';

echo "
<script>
  var phpdata = '$var';
</script>
";
```

Comment: Thats not it. It was not for variables for but ECHOS!!!

Comment: Read the question carefully please.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName what link are you talking about? I think you've accidentally posted on the wrong answer. I don't have any links in my answer.